# Postegresql slow connect time on Windows

Tags: windows, postgresql, psycopg2

I noticed that the connection to PostgreSQL is pretty slow.

```
import psycopg2
import time

start_time = time.time()
try:
    db = psycopg2.connect("dbname='xx' user='xxx' host='127.0.0.1' password='xxx' port='5433'")
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    exit(1)

print('connect time', time.time() - start_time)
```

Usual connect time is 2.5-3.5 seconds.
connect time 3.3095390796661377

Its pretty much default configuration of freshly installed PostgreSQL.
I turned off log_hostname but it changed nothing. I have run both PostgreSQL 9.4 and 10 and both have the same problem.
I'm using this machine for development, but even so, I noticed it because my Django requests take 2.5-3.5 seconds which make it unbearable even for development.

Windows 10
Python 2/3 
psycopg2 2.7.4

[image: Here packet dump]

Here relevant logs with max debug from PostgreSQL

```
2018-03-19 21:24:43.654 +03 [10048] DEBUG:  00000: forked new backend, pid=21268 socket=5072
2018-03-19 21:24:43.654 +03 [10048] LOCATION:  BackendStartup, postmaster.c:4099
2018-03-19 21:24:45.248 +03 [21268] LOG:  00000: connection received: host=127.0.0.1 port=9897
```

It fork new backend and then only 2 seconds later logs connection received

UPD

Even if I manage to avoid connection delay of PostgreSQL ( for example via pgbouncer, or if PostgreSQL running in docker) request still take 1.3-2seconds, but from first sent package till last its only 0.022 second, all other time idk what is happening but not a network communication between client and server. Same code if run within docker - 0.025 second. From windows - 1.3-2sec but network interaction only 0.022sec

There actually two problems that might be caused by same thing or different, no idea.

1) Postgresql not sending the packet for 1.8 seconds for an unknown reason

2) Even if the first problem eliminated and network interaction down to 0.022 sec whole thing still take 1.3-2 sec ( using either psql or psycopg2)

Comment: Don't connect too often. BTW: I've got the feeling this is a Windows issue, what happens if you try to connect to a non-windows server?

Comment: This is on a Raspberry-pi-3: `postgres@ingrid ~/sql $ python testcon.py
('connect time', 0.01757502555847168)
postgres@ingrid ~/sql $ ` So,it mustbeWindows (or your machine is overcommitted) BTW: the portnumber `5433`: do you have a load balancer, or multiple installations?

Comment: @wildplasser i dont connect too often :) Its basically same time every time i connect no matter how often i connect. I launched pg in docker container and tried to connect to it. 1.3-2sec. Its definitely faster than to native postgresql, but still slow. port 5433 - because i have both pg 9 and 10, 9 on 5432 10 on 5433. My machine is fine, superfast ssd + 8core ryzen and i just rebooted it, nothing changes. I suspect windows too but dont know where to dig ..

Comment: `I launched pg in docker container` say no more. (maybe you should add some tags?)

Comment: @wildplasser tags like what? I tried mysql. Connect time 0.007 so its something with postgresql...

Comment: @wildplasser i mean i launched it in docker only for testing vs native launch without docker... Original question about postgresql without docker

Comment: @klin antivirus and firewall both off. And for example mysql works perfectly fine - 0.07 seconds for connect.

Comment: Take a look at this thread https://serverfault.com/questions/323356/postgres-connection-establishment-slow it's on Unix but may still help speed up in windows too. http://pydanny-event-notes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/DjangoConEurope2012/10-steps-to-better-postgresql-performance.html

Comment: FWIW on my SSD win 10 laptop

D:\temp>py temp_connect_time.py
connect time 0.031980037689208984

Comment: @Slumdog nice for you :) I still have 2.0799999237060547 ...

Comment: and thats with pgbouncer.. without its 4 seconds xD