# Postgres connect time delay on Windows

Tags: windows, postgresql, connection, delay

There is a long delay between "forked new backend" and "connection received", from about 200 to 13000 ms. Postgres 12.2, Windows Server 2016.
During this delay the client is waiting for the network packet to start the authentication. Example:

```
14:26:33.312 CEST 3184 DEBUG:  forked new backend, pid=4904 socket=5340
14:26:33.771 CEST 172.30.100.238 [unknown] 4904 LOG: connection received: host=* port=56983
```

This was discussed earlier here:
[Postegresql slow connect time on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49353881/postegresql-slow-connect-time-on-windows)
But I have not found a solution.
After rebooting the server the delay is much shorter, about 50 ms. Then it gradually increases in the course of a few hours. There are about 100 clients connected.
I use ip addresses only in "pg_hba.conf". "log_hostname" is off.
There is BitDefender running on the server but switching it off did not help. Further, Postgres files are excluded from BitDefender checks.

I used Process Monitor which revealed the following: Forking the postgres.exe process needs 3 to 4 ms. Then, after loading DLLs, postgres.exe is looking for custom and extended locale info of 648 locales. It finds none of these. This locale search takes 560 ms (there is a gap of 420 ms, though). Perhaps this step can be skipped by setting a connection parameter. After reading some TCP/IP parameters, there are no events for 388 ms. This time period overlaps the 420 ms mentioned above. Then postgres.exe creates a thread. The total connection time measured by the client was 823 ms.

Locale example, performed 648 times:

```
"02.9760160","RegOpenKey","HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CustomLocale","REPARSE","Desired Access: Read"
"02.9760500","RegOpenKey","HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CustomLocale","SUCCESS","Desired Access: Read"
"02.9760673","RegQueryValue","HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CustomLocale\bg-BG","NAME NOT FOUND","Length: 532"
"02.9760827","RegCloseKey","HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CustomLocale","SUCCESS",""
"02.9761052","RegOpenKey","HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\ExtendedLocale","REPARSE","Desired Access: Read"
"02.9761309","RegOpenKey","HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\ExtendedLocale","SUCCESS","Desired Access: Read"
"02.9761502","RegQueryValue","HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\ExtendedLocale\bg-BG","NAME NOT FOUND","Length: 532"
"02.9761688","RegCloseKey","HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\ExtendedLocale","SUCCESS",""
```

No events for 388 ms:

```
"03.0988152","RegCloseKey","HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip6\Parameters\Winsock","SUCCESS",""
"03.4869332","Thread Create","","SUCCESS","Thread ID: 2036"
```

Comment: Use something like Process Monitor to figure out what the process is doing in the mean time.

Comment: Please [edit] the question and copy relevant parts of the output there.